# GetClipboardData (CF_UNICODETEXT);

Tags: c++, unicode, clipboard

Tell me please, why I get this issues:

- if clipboard contains unicode chars (e.q. russian) I get only first selected word. First word before "space" character.
- if clipboard not contains unicode chars (english only) I get first character of the selected text.

Get selected text:

```
CStringA getClipboard()
{
     CStringA strData;

     if (OpenClipboard(NULL)){

         HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
         char *pchData = (char*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
         strData = pchData;
         GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
         CloseClipboard();

    }
    return strData;
}
```

Set text:

```
bool setClipboard(CStringA textToclipboard)
{
    bool success = true;

    if (OpenClipboard(NULL)){

        EmptyClipboard();
        HGLOBAL hClipboardData;
        size_t size = (textToclipboard.GetLength()+1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
        hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(NULL, size);
        TCHAR* pchData = (TCHAR*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
        memcpy(pchData, LPCTSTR(textToclipboard.GetString()), size);
        SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hClipboardData);
        GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
        CloseClipboard();
    }

    return success;

}
```

Simply get and set clipboard contents.

```
CStringA str = getClipboard();
setClipboard(str);
```

Comment: CStringA is an ANSI string - for UNICODE you need CStringW.

Comment: Not working. I get symbols B5:AB and strange "corners"

Comment: Isn't `CF_UNICODETEXT` UTF-16, i.e. the standard `W` format string, which means for standard ascii, you'll only get one character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`CF_UNICODETEXT` uses UTF-16.  On Windows, `wchar_t` data elements are used for UTF-16, but your code is using `char` instead.  `CStringA` is not compatible with UTF-16.  You are mismatching the data in both functions, that is why you do not get the results you are expecting.

One solution is to use `CStringW` instead of `CStringA`:

```
CStringW getClipboard()
{
    CStringW strData;

    if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
        if (hClipboardData)
        {
            WCHAR *pchData = (WCHAR*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
            if (pchData)
            {
                strData = pchData;
                GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
            }
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    return strData;
}

bool setClipboard(CStringW textToclipboard)
{
    bool success = true;

    if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        size_t size = (textToclipboard.GetLength()+1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
        HGLOBAL hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(NULL, size);
        if (hClipboardData)
        {
            WCHAR* pchData = (WCHAR*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
            if (pchData)
            {
                memcpy(pchData, (WCHAR*) textToclipboard.GetString(), size);
                GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
                SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hClipboardData);
            }
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    return success;
}
```

If you need to stick with `CStringA`, then either:

1. use `CF_TEXT` instead of `CF_UNICODETEXT` and let the clipboard handle conversions between Ansi and Unicode for you:

   ```
   CStringA getClipboard()
   {
       CStringA strData;

       if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
       {
           HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
           if (hClipboardData)
           {
               CHAR *pchData = (CHAR*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
               if (pchData)
               {
                   strData = pchData;
                   GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
               }
           }
           CloseClipboard();
       }
       return strData;
   }

   bool setClipboard(CStringA textToclipboard)
   {
       bool success = true;

       if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
       {
           EmptyClipboard();
           size_t size = (textToclipboard.GetLength()+1) * sizeof(CHAR);
           HGLOBAL hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(NULL, size);
           if (hClipboardData)
           {
               CHAR* pchData = (CHAR*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
               if (pchData)
               {
                   memcpy(pchData, (CHAR*) textToclipboard.GetString(), size);
                   GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
                   SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hClipboardData);
               }
           }
           CloseClipboard();
       }
       return success;
   }
   ```
2. convert to/from UTF-16 manually when using `CF_UNICODETEXT`:

   ```
   CStringA getClipboard()
   {
       CStringW strData;

       if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
       {
           HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
           if (hClipboardData)
           {
               WCHAR *pchData = (WCHAR*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
               if (pchData)
               {
                   strData = pchData;
                   GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
               }
           }
           CloseClipboard();
       }

       return CStringA((WCHAR*)strData.GetString());
   }

   bool setClipboard(CStringA strData)
   {
       CStringW textToclipboard((CHAR*)strData.GetString());
       bool success = true;

       if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
       {
           EmptyClipboard();
           size_t size = (textToclipboard.GetLength()+1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
           HGLOBAL hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(NULL, size);
           if (hClipboardData)
           {
               WCHAR* pchData = (WCHAR*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
               if (pchData)
               {
                   memcpy(pchData, (WCHAR*) textToclipboard.GetString(), size);
                   GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
                   SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hClipboardData);
               }
           }
           CloseClipboard();
       }
       return success;
   }
   ```

Another solution is to use `CString` instead of either `CStringA` or `CStringW`, and then use `CF_TEXT` or `CF_UNICODETEXT` depending on whether `TCHAR` is Ansi or Unicode:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CF_TEXT_T CF_UNICODETEXT
#else
#define CF_TEXT_T CF_TEXT
#endif

CString getClipboard()
{
    CString strData;

    if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT_T);
        if (hClipboardData)
        {
            TCHAR *pchData = (TCHAR*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
            if (pchData)
            {
                strData = pchData;
                GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
            }
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    return strData;
}

bool setClipboard(CString textToclipboard)
{
    bool success = true;

    if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        size_t size = (textToclipboard.GetLength()+1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
        HGLOBAL hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(NULL, size);
        if (hClipboardData)
        {
            TCHAR* pchData = (TCHAR*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
            if (pchData)
            {
                memcpy(pchData, (TCHAR*) textToclipboard.GetString(), size);
                GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
                SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT_T, hClipboardData);
            }
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I change CStringA to CStringW and char* to WCHAR* and its working perfectly! With English all languages! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Both of them are Unicode...

But in Unicode, more that one byte represents a character. For example maybe 2 bytes is used for a character. Therefore:

When it's Russian, the string is like

```
                                                            '\0'
                                                            ----
0x04 0x3F 0x04 0x40 0x04 0x38 0x04 0x32 0x04 0x35 0x04 0x42 0x00 0x20
~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~
    п         р         и        в          е         т       space
```

It reads until space.

When it's English, the string is like

```
'\0'
----
0x00 0x48 0x00 0x65 0x00 0x6C 0x00 0x6C 0x00 0x6F 0x00 0x20
~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~
   H          e         l        l          o       space
```

It reads nothing. (If you read first, it's because of order of storing bytes, LE or BE)

*Note: Maybe I'm not precision in choosing words (Unicode, UTF, ...)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. But please explain me how I can use it.

Comment: Maybe terminology is incorrect (I don't know or care) but explanation is great. Extra points for the diagrams. :-)

Comment: Ok, I try to change this line: strData = pchData; I need another conversion?

Comment: In English i get the first character.

Comment: @user1537809: Maybe [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?454864-Get-Clipboard-Text-as-String) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/446/Unicode-MBCS-and-Generic-text-mappings), are useful links.

Comment: He actually reads 1 character in the second case (English, ASCII only character set) because the format is actually UTF-16LE and looks like `0x48 0x00`, which terminates the string after the first character.