# C++ MFC- strcpy error

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm fairly new to C++ MFC programming. I'm having a hard time on understanding the code of C++. Just came from Java programming and it seems a whole new world to me. This is a long way from Android development.

Can you guys help me understand this problem here?

Here is the complete code

```
CString c;
code.GetWindowText(c);
AfxMessageBox(c);

OpenClipboard();
EmptyClipboard();

// Setup a memory HANDLE for the clipboard
HANDLE hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, c.GetLength() + 1);
char* pStr = (char*)GlobalLock(hMem); 
strcpy(pStr, c); //error here 
GlobalUnlock(hMem);

// Tell Clipboard to use our handle now.
::SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);

CloseClipboard();
```

This part of the function copies the `CString` and assigns it to the clipboard.
I'm getting the error

> no suitable conversion function from CString to const char* exist.

I had an online reference and this is the code and other comments didn't seem to have the same problem. I'm wondering what the heck is wrong with mine.

Comment: see this link for copying Unicode text to clipboard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362859/getclipboarddata-cf-unicodetext

Answer (score 3):

The default build these days is Unicode, which uses 16-bit `wchar_t` characters that are incompatible with the `char` type.

`CString` comes in two specialized variants, `CStingA` for `char` characters and `CStringW` for `wchar_t` characters. If you use `CStringA` it will allow an automatic conversion to `const char *`.

A better way to go would be to use `CF_UNICODETEXT` and keep using the normal `CString`. You'll need to use `wcscpy` in place of `strcpy`, and allocate twice the number of bytes.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the information. Do you have any online reference for this I would like to read more about these kind of datatypes.

Comment: And how do you allocate the number of bytes twice? I noticed when I edited my program I only did get like half of the string.

Comment: Okay, I found an alternative way. I'm not sure if it's advisable though. I just changed  c.GetLength() + 1 to ( c.GetLength() + 1)* 2 and it worked.

Comment: @OrdinaryProgrammer That's exactly what I was going to say.